# Efficiency of a dehumidifier with respect to temperature

Tags: water, applied-physics, humidity

I have just bought a dehumidifier to decrease humidity in my bedroom.

I'm wondering if it takes more energy to work (assuming same liters of water condensed) in winter with cold temperatures or in summer with high temperatures.

By which law is your reasoning deducted?

thanks

Comment: Applied physics, why would that be off topic @David Z ? Dehumidifiers are less necessary in summer because there is then more water vapor in the air that eneters the house.

Comment: @Pieter You can't just ask any random question about how something works, call it applied physics, and expect it to be on topic here. The question has to focus on the science, which this does not. That being said, now that I look at it again, it's probably just a minor edit away from being on topic; for example it could ask how the energy required to condense a certain volume of water varies with the air temperature, though even in that case I'd expect to see some research effort on f126ck's part.

Comment: @DavidZ In my opinion one chooses the site where one is most likely to get the best answers.